# How to find how much memory is actually used up by a malloc call?

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, malloc

If I call:

```
char *myChar = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char));
```

I am likely to be using more than 1 byte of memory, because malloc is likely to be using some memory on its own to keep track of free blocks in the heap, and it may effectively cost me some memory by always aligning allocations along certain boundaries.

**My question is**: Is there a way to find out how much memory is really used up by a particular `malloc` call, including the effective cost of alignment, and the overhead used by `malloc`/`free`?

Just to be clear, I am *not* asking to find out how much memory a pointer points to after a call to `malloc`.  Rather, I am debugging a program that uses a great deal of memory, and I want to be aware of which parts of the code are allocating how much memory.  I'd like to be able to have internal memory accounting that very closely matches the numbers reported by top.  Ideally, I'd like to be able to do this programmatically on a per-`malloc`-call basis, as opposed to getting a summary at a checkpoint.

Comment: Shouldn't you be doing `char* myChar = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char*));`

Comment: @KristerAndersson or since it's C: `char *myChar = malloc(sizeof(*myChar));`. You're allocating the size of a `char *`, but he's creating a pointer to `char`.

Comment: @KristerAndersson Not at all... Please read again the doc about `malloc`. That said, `sizeof(char)` is not needed at all, as it will always be one (guaranteed by the C standard).

Comment: @KristerAndersson: No, he shouldn't.  If the pointer is a `char *` then the size of the objects it points to is `sizeof(char)`.  The OP is correct.

Comment: Wouldn't that be nondeterministic (different padding between program runs) and different on different implementations of C and different OSs? I mean even you will be able to find out exact numbers, would there be a guarantee they will be same next time?

Comment: @KristerAndersson: The original code is correct.  It is allocating a memory block that takes up only 1 byte (`sizeof(char)`), and then returning a pointer to that memory.  What you are proposing allocates 4 bytes (`sizeof(char*)`), and would require `myChar` to be declares as a `char**` instead.

Comment: `char *my_char = malloc(1);` No casts or sizeof needed.

Comment: @Pubby: `malloc()` returns a `void*`.  A type-cast is needed to assign that to a `char*` variable.

Comment: Yet the answer is still no, it's implementation defined.

Comment: @RemyLebeau-TeamB I don't see C++ tagged ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There isn't a portable solution to this, however there may be operating-system specific solutions for the environments you're interested in.

For example, with `glibc` on Linux, you can use the `mallinfo()` function from `<malloc.h>` which returns a `struct mallinfo`.  The `uordblks` and `hblkhd` members of this structure contains the dynamically allocated address space used by the program including book-keeping overhead - if you take the difference of this before and after each `malloc()` call, you will know the amount of space used by that call.  (The overhead is not necessarily constant for every call to `malloc()`).

Using your example:

```
char *myChar;
size_t s = sizeof(char);
struct mallinfo before, after;
int mused;

before = mallinfo();
myChar = malloc(s);
after = mallinfo();

mused = (after.uordblks - before.uordblks) + (after.hblkhd - before.hblkhd);

printf("Requested size %zu, used space %d, overhead %zu\n", s, mused, mused - s);
```

Really though, the overhead is likely to be pretty minor unless you are making a very very high number of very small allocations, which is a bad idea anyway.

Comment: uordblks is a 32-bit signed integer. It won't work if I allocate more than 2GB.

Comment: There is a `mallinfo2` that solves this problem. (Though it's less portable.)

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on the implementation. You should really use some memory debugger. On Linux Valgrind's Massif tool can be useful. There are memory debugging libraries like dmalloc, ...

That said, typical overhead:

- 1 int for storing size + flags of this block.
- possibly 1 int for storing size of previous/next block, to assist in coallescing blocks.
- 2 pointers, but these may only be used in `free()`'d blocks, being reused for application storage in allocated blocks.
- Alignment to an approppriate type, e.g: `double`.
- -1 int (yes, that's a minus) of the next/previous chunk's field containing our size if we are an allocated block, since we cannot be coallesced until we're freed.

So, a minimum size can be 16 to 24 bytes. and minimum overhead can be 4 bytes.

But you could also satisfy every allocation via mapping memory pages (typically 4Kb), which would mean overhead for smaller allocations would be huge. I think OpenBSD does this.

Comment: Thanks, @ninjalj, this is also a very helpful answer!

Comment: Standard C and C++ library on MacOS X use the size rounded up to a multiple of 16 bytes if necessary for small sizes. Malloc blocks of identical size are stored in one bigger block, and the only overhead is one bit per block.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing defined in the C library to query the total amount of physical memory used by a `malloc()` call.  The amount of memory allocated is controlled by whatever memory manager is hooked up behind the scenes that `malloc()` calls into.  That memory manager can allocate as much extra memory as it deemes necessary for its internal tracking purposes, on top of whatever extra memory the OS itself requires.  When you call `free()`, it accesses the memory manager, which knows how to access that extra memory so it all gets released properly, but there is no way for you to know how much memory that involves.  If you need that much fine detail, then you need to write your own memory manager.

Answer (score 0):

If you do use valgrind/Massif, there's an option to show either the `malloc` value or the `top` value, which differ a LOT in my experience.  Here's an excerpt from the Valgrind manual http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/ms-manual.html :

> ...However, if you wish to measure all the memory used by your program,
>   you can use the --pages-as-heap=yes. When this option is enabled,
>   Massif's normal heap block profiling is replaced by lower-level page
>   profiling. Every page allocated via mmap and similar system calls is
>   treated as a distinct block. This means that code, data and BSS
>   segments are all measured, as they are just memory pages. Even the
>   stack is measured...