# Is the size of a dynamically allocated array stored somewhere in RAM?

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

I was wondering if the size of a dynamically allocated array is stored somewhere in memory because calling `free()` function on a pointer initialized by `malloc()` or its family frees the memory accurately.

So if `free()` knows exactly how much memory to de-allocate,doesn't that mean that the size value is stored somewhere in memory?

Can we retrieve this value?

Comment: It should depend on the implementation of the library.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8335402/how-to-find-how-much-memory-is-actually-used-up-by-a-malloc-call

Comment: @layzak simply see source code of (g)libc; aim for the definition of free/malloc - https://github.com/lattera/glibc/tree/master/malloc - actually, yeah, it stores both begin and end of used mem block.

Comment: Highly related/maybe dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1518711/how-does-free-know-how-much-to-free, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/197675/how-does-delete-know-the-size-of-the-operand-array

Comment: It is highly implementation dependant. On unixes, malloc is a higher lever abstraction above sbreak or mmap that has its own book keeping structures. But unless you want to develop an allocation library, you as a C or C++ programmer should considere `malloc` - `free` or `new` - `delete` as an opaque dynamic allocation system.

Comment: This is an awesome explanation about how malloc work (on osx) http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2010/05/look-at-how-malloc-works-on-mac.html

Comment: @Olaf I though we closed this question?

Comment: @2501: At least I CVed as dup (didn't see the actual close). Who re-opened without commenting?

Comment: @Olaf I closed it with gold-hammer, and it was closed for a few minutes, but it was magically reopened without any traces.

Comment: @2501: A mod gone wild? it clearly is a dup. Not sure if that was it, but: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5451104/how-to-get-memory-block-length-after-malloc

Comment: @2501: flagged for mod. At least leaving a comment would be the polite way.

Comment: I reopened it. The duplicate was not close enough. In my humble opinion, naturally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may well be; that would indeed be a sensible *implementation* of the C standard library.

But it's not guaranteed by the C standard.

There's nothing stopping me from writing a C-standard compliant library that *always* allocates a fixed amount of memory for every `malloc` call! (And return appropriately if you're asking for an amount in excess of that fixed value). Then I would *not* need to store the amount allocated anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

`malloc()` is a library wrapper function over many levels of low-layer memory allocation call. It hides details like the size of actual memory size allocated by the memory allocator of the OS and directly returns a valid pointer (in case of success) to the application making the call. The pointer can be used safely (within the bounds) and passed to `free()` after the usage is done.

The pointer returned as the return value of `malloc()` need not be (*and most of the time, it's not*) the *actual* address returned by the memory allocator. OS/ memory allocator does some book-keeping under the hood to keep the track of size of allocated memory and then after some adjustments, it passes a pointer to the `malloc()` which is then returned to the application calling `malloc()`.

There is no *standard* way of getting the actual info (*it was meant to be hidden from the user, because of proper reasons, IMHO*), but there are platform-dependent ways of getting the info.

Comment: is it the same behavior if i use C or C++?

Comment: @KevinWallis why in C++ you would like to use `malloc()`?

Comment: Normally not because there is a `new` keyword but it is possible i thought :D

Comment: @KevinWallis Yes, that's the reason i asked __why__, not __how__. :)

Comment: "The pointer returned ...is not the actual address returned by the memory allocator." is not specified by C.

Comment: @chux Right, but that will be part of OS documentation, not C, essentially. Please correct me if I'm wrong...

Comment: It really is not an OS issue as the compiler can layer its own memory management on top of what ever the OS, if any, provides.  The compiler does not need to document how it handles memory management to be compliant beyond that it meets the C spec.

Comment: @chux right, I tewaked the wordings a bit, is it any better?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using glibc there is the non-standard malloc_usable_size method that you can use. It may return a larger number than the number of bytes that you allocated, though.

Comment: It would make sense that it would return more bytes than you allocated because the size values stored in the header and footer of malloc allocated memory blocks include the size of the header and footer.

Comment: The header and footer bytes are not included in the return-value from malloc_usable_size. malloc just allocates more memory than asked for in many cases. When and how much extra memory seems to depend on the specific architecture and the current position of the moon, though.

Answer (score 0):

> Is the size of a dynamically allocated array stored somewhere in RAM?

Maybe.  Maybe not.

C does *not* specify how the memory management is implemented.  If portable code needs the size allocate for a pointer, it must handle that itself.

---

Select platforms do provide helper functions as some systems do include a size stored in memory.  Others encode the size in the pointer, fixed sizes per block of memory, etc.